# Angularjs $rootScope in resolve sometimes not updating in template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

For some reason, my `$rootScope.user` variable in my resolve function does not finish assigning the data before my `view.html` template loads.

Most of the time, I will be able to do `{{ $root.user.uid }}` in my template and I will be able to see the variable data, but sometimes it won't show up.

I'm a bit confused on why this would happen because doesn't a resolve have to run FIRST before the template loads?

Does anyone know why this would be happening?

**NOTE:** If I add a `console.log($rootScope.user.uid)` before `deferred.resolve();` it always shows up, just not showing the variable in the template.

```
.factory('Auth', function($http, $state, $q, $rootScope) {
    var factory = {workflowItemCheck: workflowItemCheck };
    return factory;

   function workflowItemCheck(workflow_id) { return $http.post('/auth/workflow', {workflow_id:workflow_id}); }
})


.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    var workflow_item_auth = ['$q', 'Auth', '$rootScope', '$stateParams', function ($q, Auth, $rootScope, $stateParams) { 

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        Auth.workflowItemCheck($stateParams.workflow_id).then(function(data){ 
            $rootScope.user = { uid: data.data.uid };
            deferred.resolve(); 
        }, function(){ deferred.reject(); });

        return deferred.promise;
    }];


    $stateProvider.state(
        'workflow2.view', { 
            url: '/:workflow_id/view', 
            templateUrl: 'pages/templates/workflow/view.html',
        }, 
        controller: 'workflow.view', 
        resolve: { authenticated: workflow_item_auth } 
    })



})
```

### *PLEASE NOTE*: There is nothing in the controller. This is specifically getting my $rotoScope to the template.

Comment: since you don't show any HTML templates here it isn't obvious why you are having a problem, but in general using `$rootScope` is an anti-pattern;  it is entirely possible that you aren't seeing the same object that you are trying to update do to the way scope inheritance works.  You should use a service to hold shared variables instead of using `$rootScope`.

Comment: @Claies pretend the template is literally just `{{ $root.user.uid }}` - gives me the same issue. It just doesn't make sense that the template won't load until my resolve is accepted and my resolve isn't accepted until the $rootScope is declared.

Comment: No, it actually makes perfect sense; $rootScope is only declared once per application.

Comment: @Claies No, it might make sense to you, but I actually *update* `$rootScope` before the template is loaded so....Please, explain what you mean or don't respond at all because it doesn't make sense to everyone.

Comment: Could you please provide the code of your controller and view? It will be easier to make any conclusions if we see it.

Comment: @DmitryBezzubenkov there isn't anything in my controller yet, I am just trying to get my data from my resolve to get to the template.

Comment: @bryan i created a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2CRGeA263dbZrUgJENSt?p=preview) based on your provided code but nothing seems wrong.

Comment: @MMhunter its probably because your data loads faster then my data..I assure you that the method of storing is flawed and I don't know why

Comment: @bryan check my plunker. i added a manually delay of 5 seconds, but it still works properly.

Comment: @MMhunter this seems to work but having a user wait 5 seconds is not good for user experience. It shouldn't need to be a waiting X seconds and hope it works kind of solution. If I knew why this was happening, maybe I could change how it worked.

Comment: Hi @bryan, could we see the code in the workflow.view controller please

Comment: @GeorgeLee here is nothing in the controller. This is specifically getting the $root.user.uid to display in the template from my resolve.

Comment: @bryan  no the manual delay is just to pretend there is a delay in your response, to show that it is not the delay causing your problem.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out *why* it's happening and what I can seriously do to fix it. I always knew it had to do with the resolve @MMhunter

Comment: What is the value of stateParams.workflow_id? The code seems fine so I'm trying to see if the environment is changing that would create a break.

Answer (score 3):

your resolve isn't returning a promise so at the time it is resolving your workflow_item_auth might not be set. If your resolve returns a promise, it won't navigate to your view until it is resolved.

```
$stateProvider.state(
        'v1', {
            url: '/:workflow_id/view',
            templateUrl: 'view.html',
            resolve: {
                authenticated: function(Auth, $rootScope, $stateParams) {
                    return Auth.workflowItemCheck($stateParams.workflow_id).then(function(data) {
                        $rootScope.user = {uid: data.data.uid};
                        return data;
                    });
                }
            }
        }
);
```

EDIT - Actually I see that you are returning a promise there. I still think there is potentially a timing issue there. I would still do it as I explained above.

Comment: how is this any different then me definite a function like my above code?

Comment: The real difference is that the resolve is using the promise that the service is returning rather than using your own promise created using $q in your resolve function.  The other thing is that when you inject "authenticated" in your controller, you will actually get the value that your service resolved. In your case, when you call deferred.resolve() you aren't passing anything. This might be moot since you probably aren't using it, but I wonder if that has something to do with the issue. My answer is based on how I've successfully done it many times which is why I suggested doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Because the backend call is async, I believe Angular already went through its digest cycle by the time your backend call completes. So, the binding isn't updated.

In your promise's resolve (where you do $rootScope.user = ..), try and add $rootScope.$apply() right after that, to refresh the bindings.

Comment: Get the following error when I try that `angular.js:11607 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress`

Answer (score 0):

I got one solution which is force that the resolve execute before loading the data into view. 
As we know, the resolve will be executed before controller if it returns a promise. And the controller is executed before view.

hope this can give you a kind of help

```
.controller('workflow.view', ['$rootScope', 'authUser', function($rootScope, authUser){
$rootScope.user = { uid: authUser.data.uid };}])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
$stateProvider.state(
    'workflow2.view', { 
        url: '/:workflow_id/view', 
        templateUrl: 'pages/templates/workflow/view.html',
    }, 
    controller: 'workflow.view', 
    resolve: { 
        Auth : 'Auth',
        authUser: function(Auth,$stateParams){
           return Auth.workflowItemCheck($stateParams.workflow_id);
        }
    } 
})})
```